# How to use Spark for incremental data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm working with Spark (Scala) to perform a batch process that occurs each week.
Each day, we have a daily feed of Sales data with the following schema:
Day, product, sales

Each week, we would like to import all the daily data of that week, aggregate the daily sales to find the average sales per week for each product. We then export a file with the following headers :
Week, product, sales_average
(and we merge it with the previous weekly aggregates)

The problem here is that we can receive **updates** for already computed aggregations. For example, let's suppose that we're in week 1 and we already computed the weekly average for each product of that week.
In the next week (week 2) I can receive a daily sales row where the Day column refers to the previous week (Week 1) instead of Week 2. Consequently, the already computed value of Week1 for the corresponding product is no longer accurate, and we need to take again all daily data of that week and that product and do the aggregation again.

The most straightforward (and worst) solution is to just import all the data and compute ALL aggregations each week. This obviously will lead to performance bottlenecks, especially that we're dealing with 2 years of data. What I would like to do is:

- Compute aggregations (average) for the current (new week)
- Recompute aggregations of the last weeks where we have an update (not all of the data: we would only consider daily data of the week where there has been an update).

I've read some about Structured Streaming Programming, time windows but I'm new to Spark and this all felt a little bit complicated to take in.
So any help on how to solve this will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Depends on where your data lives and how you are getting it into spark... If dev effort is concerning, you could look at a tool like Elasticsearch that would let you do all this using simple rest queries (it has spark integration too) in a distributed fashion.

Comment: Data lives in s3 files . I'm importing files into spark dataframes. The main concern here is performance ( how to aggregate without loading all data)

Comment: With flat files I don't see any way to do the aggregation without ingesting all the data again unless you store enough metadata about the aggregations. Still this would get complex. Looks like you'll need a database backend to do what you need

Comment: What would you suggest ?

Comment: I probably need a thorough understanding of the data flow and application objective to answer that question. Is your application for batch processing or continuous online processing? You mentioned data for a past week can appear in the following week(s), is there an end to this or could it just appear anywhere say 3 months from now?

Comment: Is the application going to evolve or would just be doing this simple batch reporting? What is the size of the combined data we are talking about? So on and so forth... To your point about Spark structured streaming, looks like the latest version does seem to be able to save state(bucket metadata) to hdfs backed file system. So this should in theory be sufficient if the data flow fits into it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following for streaming aggregations over a Structured Streaming’s windowing strategy could help:

https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/08/event-time-aggregation-watermarking-apache-sparks-structured-streaming.html